# Angular 2 - Why my all routes are not redirected?

Tags: angular, redirect, routes, angular-routing, angular-component-router

```
[{
    path: 'menu',
    component: MenuComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'how',
    component: HowItWorksComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    redirectTo: 'menu'
  }]
```

Above is my root route config why my all routes are not redirected to the menu because empty string should be a prefix to all routes. 
It shows respective components on `/how` and `/menu` and perfectly redirects to menu on `/` but it should always redirect to `/menu` shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `useAsDefault` on `/menu`.

```
[{
   path: 'menu',
   component: MenuComponent,
   useAsDefault: true,
},
...
```

Comment: I don't get the point, why should I? According to victor's post http://vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes this should always mount the menu component

Comment: infact any 404 should also be redirected to menu

Answer (score 0):

If you want your last path to catch anything that the first two don't, then you'll want:

```
{
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: 'menu'
}
```

As [explained in the angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#basics-config), `**` is a special wildcard route